# Can I download contents remotely by "git pull staff master" for as many times as I want?

Tags: github, git-pull, git-remote

I downloaded a bunch of files into a local folder by "git pull staff master" a few days ago. But I deleted the entire folder by mistake. Then I tried to download those files again by "git pull staff master" again. Although I got

```
From ...(URL)
* branch      master    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date
```

I didn't have files in fact downloaded in the folder. During those days, I didn't make any changes. The URL of the remote repo remained the same.

How can I download those files again? Is there a setting like "can only git pull once" that prevents me from downloading those files for more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as git pull only once.

If you accidentally deleted all your file, see if it is still in the git by doing `git status`, and the deleted file should be indicated as `deleted`.

If you want to restore the file, use `git checkout FILENAME`. If you deleted the entire content of the folder, you can do `git checkout .` (notice the dot `.`) to restore all the files.

Comment: Thank you very much. That definitely helps!

Comment: Yes, of course! That message was implying that I couldn't do so until 7 minutes later. I'll tick it as soon as the platform allows me.